# How to link users model to multiple models in laravel

Tags: eloquent-relationship, laravel-10

I am having trouble figuring out how to port an old php 5.6 script(corydating) sql file to laravel.
How do i attach muttiple models to the user model?
I have Gender table, Countries table, Cities table, States table, Hair color, Eye color and many more about 20 tables with their columns.
And the user table will get the user's selected data like so

```
$table->increments('HairColorID');
        $table->string('L1HairColor', 20);
        $table->string('L2HairColor', 40);
        $table->string('L3HairColor', 20);
        $table->string('L4HairColor', 20);
        $table->smallInteger('TopSorted')->default(0);
```

The above code is from the hair color table
and the user table will get the selected hair color like so

'''

```
$table->unsignedSmallInteger('GenderID')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedSmallInteger('HeightID')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedSmallInteger('Age')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedSmallInteger('BodyTypeID')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedSmallInteger('HairColorID')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedSmallInteger('EyeColorID')->nullable
```

'''
So want to create a model for all these model and link them to together
but the problem is how do i create the relationships and what relationship type should i use?
One to one?
One to many?
Many to many?
I can't find a single example like my case
all the examples are using just 3 models but i have more than 3 so i am confused.

Please help.

Thanks in advance